# jQuery UI Tabs: Several sets of tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the jQuery UI Tabs for individual real estate listings... the listing are generated on the fly from the DB.

I'm curious if there's a better way of associating tabs and their respective DIV fragments (containers) than individual IDs per tab group:

```
#tabContent1_1
#tabContent2_1
#tabContent3_1
...

#tabContent1_2
#tabContent2_2
#tabContent3_2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way, as far as I know. HTML is pretty flat -- you get divs, ids, classes, and your imagination. You could at least use better names, though, like this:

```
#SalesTabs_1
#SalesTabs_2
#SalesTabs_3
...

#EmployeeTabs_1
#EmployeeTabs_2
#EmployeeTabs_3
...
```